# strange segmentation violation

Tags: c++, crash, segmentation-fault, stack-trace

I have a crash, from my log:

```
15:21:12  1645 Wrk-0.14 | *** Break ***: segmentation violation
```

the stack trace is:

```
===========================================================
There was a crash.
This is the entire stack trace of all threads:
===========================================================
...
#4  <signal handler called>
#5  0x00002b5eeef98865 in HiggsSelector::RejectBadJet (this=0x1de241a0, 
    index_jet=0, index_leading=0, index_subleading=1) at HiggsSelector.C:2375
```

the function is:

```
bool HiggsSelector::RejectBadJet(int index_jet, int index_leading, int index_subleading) const
{
    assert(index_jet >= 0);
    assert(index_leading >= 0);
    assert(index_subleading >= 0);
    assert(PV_z);
    int index_PV_ID_chosen=0; //<-----in your header
    double DiPhoton_zcommon=z_common_corrected(index_leading,index_subleading,false);
    float minimal_distance=9999;
    for (unsigned int index_PV=0;index_PV<PV_z->size()-1;index_PV++) {
      if ( fabs((*PV_z)[index_PV]-DiPhoton_zcommon)<minimal_distance) {
```

the last line is the number 2375. I really don't undertand how this crash is possibile, I think I've checked everythings with the `assert`s. `PV_z` is a `*std::vector<float>`

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you access that array via `PV_z->at(index_PV)` instead?

Comment: A pointer can be `>=0` but can be at the same time already deleted - if it has not been set to NULL after it was deleted. Then you would make an access violation.

Comment: Check if the pointer is valid, not just if it is a null pointer, if you `delete PV_z` and forget to nullify it, it will point to junk.

Comment: is this multithreading code?
because during the assert(PV_z) and the use of it, someone else can delete it

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev/@SingerOfTheFall: right, but it cannot be the case. @nobs: it is multiprocess, all the processes are independent

Comment: Are you sure `PV_z->size()` is not `0`?

Comment: Just another stupid question: Are the assertions enabled (i.e. not deactivated with some NDEBUG somewhere)?

Comment: I know you've already stated it, but are you sure you have `std::vector<float> *PV_z = new std::vector<float>` (i.e. it is really a pointer) vs. `std::vector<float> PV_z`? I don't see the declaration in the code, so double-checking that might be good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `PV_z->size() == 0`, then `PV_z->size()-1` underflows to `UINT_MAX`, and you could easily get a segmentation violation since the for-loop condition is always true.

One way to fix it:

```
for (unsigned int index_PV=0; !PV_z->empty() && index_PV<PV_z->size()-1;index_PV++) {
                            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't discard that PV_z points *to the moon*, which will bypass the assert.